# Why does this bash script always execute the else part?

Tags: bash, if-statement

```
for e in $( ls $1 ); do
    if [ -d $e ]; then
        echo -n "Directory $e has words="
    else 
        echo -n "File $e has words="
    fi
    echo -n $e | wc -c
done
```

The above script always executes the else part, though there are directories in $1. What is the mistake that I have made?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not, in echoes once for a file and a dir. Checked on my machine.

Comment: `ls $1` is listing files and subdirectories in the directory `$1`, but `[ -d $e ]` is looking in the current directory. Use `for e in "$1"/*; do` to get the full paths to the items. More generally, [`ls` is for displaying file lists to the user, not for getting file lists programmatically](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Start by running it through https://shellcheck.net and fixing the errors.

Comment: Is your file named `$1` or `1`. If the second, try using `for e in $( ls 1 );`

Comment: Just an interesting thread about [Why **not** parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/)

Comment: learn to debug your script by "seeing" what code is being executed with what values. You do that by "wrapping" the block of code of interest with `set -x` and close with `set +x`. This will show you the values being used for the variables in your code, and then you can investigate why, for instance, `[ -d "$e" ]` is failing. Good luck.